# Azure Databricks to Azure SQL DW connection

Tags: azure-databricks, azure-synapse

Based on Databicks documentation at this link https://docs.databricks.com/data/data-sources/azure/sql-data-warehouse.html  , to be able to connect from Azure Databricks to Azure SQL DW , Database user should have "control" permissions. This is practically not possible because "control" permissions on entire DB can't be given to individual user connecting to SQL DW from Databicks. Is there an alternative solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

currently the connector uses PolyBase for high-throughput data ingestion. This means that you must grant CONTROL permissions to the user.  We are planning to remove this requirement in the future. For now you must connect and either use the standard SQLBulkCopy API or the COPY statement. The recommendation is to use the new COPY statement for high throughput ingestion and load data from the storage account: https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/statements/copy-into-transact-sql?view=azure-sqldw-latest

Comment: Thanks @kevin for sharing this information. This is very helpful. This will cover the loading part. For reading data from SQL DW to Databricks the only option is to use the Connector which uses PolyBase ? and CONTROL permissions required for user?